# Oracle sql join with 3 tables

Tags: java, sql, oracle, join, left-join

lk_state table

```
id  desc
MD  Maryland
FL  Florida
VA  Virginia
NY  NewYork
NJ  NewJersy
CA  California
```

users table

```
user_ID Name    Active  State
01      AAA     1       MA  
02      BBB     1       MD
03      CCC     1       CA
04      DDD     1       NY
05      EEE     1       NJ
06      FFF     1       FL
07      GGG     1       FL
```

users_groups table

```
id  group
01  10
02  20
03  20
04  30
05  20
06  10
07  20
```

I want to join the tables which will give me output of states in lk_state table. The condiiotn is display only those states where users belong to role=20

Output should be

```
id  desc
MD  Maryland
FL  Florida
NJ  NewJersy
CA  California
```

I tried joining but it gives me multiple rows one for each users and groups. Please help me with an oracle sql that displays as required.

Comment: "I tried joining but ..."    If you had _shown_ what you tried, someone could point out what you did wrong.  @GMB has posted a possible working solution, but it would be a better learning experience to work out from your own attempt.

Comment: Because there is a one-one relationship between "users_groups" and "users" tables and also each user has a unique state_id, the result of joining these tables could not contain multiple rows for each user. So I think you joined tables incorrectly. It's better to send your code for finding possible mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.*
FROM lk_states s, users u, users_groups g
WHERE s.id = u.state
  AND u.user_id = g.id
  AND g.group = 20
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `exists` and a correlated subquery:

```
select s.*
from lk_states s
where exists (
    select 1
    from users u
    inner join user_groups ug on ug.id = u.user_id
    where u.state = s.id and ug.group = 20
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this. Not ideal to keep the keywords as column names

```
Select s.* 
from lk_states s
JOIN users u ON u.state = s.id
JOIN users_groups ug ON ug.id = u.user_id
WHERE ug.u_group  = 20
```